# Vlookup Text within a String

Tags: string, excel, vba, wildcard, vlookup

A ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------B

## `www.dog.com`-------------------------------- Dog

## `www.firstcat.com`================   Cat

## `www.internet.com/pig`=============Pig

Apologies about the formatting.

I'm having some issues with VLookUp. Basically I want to abbreviate a URL from Column A, and  place this abbreviation in Column B as illustrated above. To do this for example with `www.dog.com`, I came up with the follwing formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"Dog"*",A:A,1,True)("Dog","")
```

Could anybody help me, and tell me what's wrong with the above formula.
Also, would Vlookup be suitable to do the same with the other two URLs? 
Finally, if it is(not) suitable, would whatever the best option be compatible with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I not sure what you are really trying to do. But there is a lot I think wrong with the formula even without understanding your goal.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"Dog"*",A:A,1,True)("Dog","")
```

1. You're lookup value with wildcards in not concatenated correctly.
2. You table array A:A should be A:B
3. The index_num should be 2.
4. The range_lookup param should be false.
5. I have not idea what ("Dog","") is trying to accomplish.

How about:

```
=VLOOKUP("*Dog*",A:B,2,FALSE)
```

You can of course do the same with `"*Cat*"` and `"*Pig*"` or with a cell reference like `"*"&C1&"*"`.

Comment: Hi Karl,

Apologies about this mistakes. I'm pretty new to these things. Just looking to automate some work.

Basically I'm not really looking for 'Dog' to accomplish anything, as such. I'm basically looking to extract data from one column and move it to another in an abbreviated form, hence my question.

Comment: Well if you know the set of abbreviations and the are all actually substrings as in your example then what I've suggested will work.

Answer (score 0):

Got these solutions anyway on another forum.

```
B1  =LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1),$F$1:$F$3)
B2  =LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A2),$F$1:$F$3)
B3  =LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A3),$F$1:$F$3)
```

And for the VBA Macro

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub ExtractData()
Dim dcp, i As Long
Dim c As Range
dcp = Array("Dog", "Cat", "Pig")
Columns(2).ClearContents
For Each c In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  For i = LBound(dcp) To UBound(dcp)
    If InStr(c, dcp(i)) Then
      c.Offset(, 1) = dcp(i)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
Next c
End Sub
```